# What do I put into the XML to read from an array?

Tags: xml, arrays, groovy, soapui

I am using soapUI and have 130 IDs that I would like to choose from and have the test pick a random one from an array.

I have a GroovyScript which looks like so:

```
IDNumbers = [1,2,3,etc.]
rand = new Random();
randomIds = IDNumbers[(rand.nextInt(130))];
```

In my XML I have the following:

```
<FacilityID>${#RandomIDs(This is the test case Groovy Script)#randomIds}</FacilityID>
```

Am I even on the right track with this?

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand your question

Comment: I want to be able to instead of hard-coding a value into the Facility ID tag in the XML have it pull a random number from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound sooo close.  Your format is bad in the XML. I'd build the groovy script like this (but I think yours will work the way it is):

```
def IDNumbers = [1,2,3]
rand = new Random();
randomIds = IDNumbers[(rand.nextInt(3))];
return randomIds
```

Now right click on your request select get data > RandomIDs > script result and you should be ready to go.  Should be probably be ${RandomIDs#result}.  Make sure your groovy script is aways run first.  If you are going to use this in many places across tests you should add it as a [property](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html).

For fun, you could also use shuffle

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Collections.shuffle(list)

return list[0]
```